# Git: how to create previous version of an application before already existing in repo

Tags: git, git-tag

I am migrating code from svn to git.

I have already pushed and tagged Component REL-v2.0 to the git, and noticed that there is previous version of the Component - REL-v1.0.

I would like to commit it to the repo before my first commit with tag 1.0 and create a second tag , to have a history like "REL-v1.0 --> REL-v2.0". 
How can I achieve it using git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a git revert to the commitId prior to what you didn't want checked in. Then you can add the 1.0 component, commit and tag, add 2.0 component, commit and tag (with -f to move the tag).

Now the revert will actually commit reverse changes from head to the prior Id. This is the best you can do if you've pushed to a remote repo. If you haven't pushed to a remote repo, you can undo your 2.0 checkin  with a [git-reparent](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent), which you will have to install from github.

Comment: Thanks a lot. git-reparent does the stuff I needed

Answer (score 0):

Tags just are labels, they do not define history structure. Just find a commit corresponding to the release 1.0 and tag it using `git tag REL-v1.0 <commitId>`

Comment: Sorry, I've edit the question. I want to commit before the first commit.